# Unit Testing with Variable Inputs

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing

I have the following code that performs unit tests on code I developed for matching reg expressions in all the files within a main directory and each sub-directory.

I am building units tests to make sure it performs well but I am very new to unit testing.

I have the following code:

```
class TestRegexMatches(unittest.TestCase):

def __init__(self,root_dir):
    self.path = root_dir

def testEmptyRegex(self):
    # Can't match negative look-ahead
    key = re.compile('(?!)')
    self.assertEqual(sum(tm.search_for_regex_match(self.path,key).values()),0)

def testIntersection(self):
    key1 = re.compile('[abc]')
    key2 = re.compile('[^abc]')
    self.assertNotEqual(tm.search_for_regex_match(self.path,key1),
                        tm.search_for_regex_match(self.path,key2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_obj = TestRegexMatches('/home/luis/test')
    unittest.main()
```

This code currently doesn't work. Normally, one would not have the **init** constructor for the unit tests but I want to be able to give the tests different directories to search under for different tests instead of hard coding the path in the `tm.search_for_regex_match` function.

Comment: You're still hard-coding the value, just in a different place. You should probably just set `self.path` in the `setUp` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick that solves what you need (but isn't good unit testing practice):

```
class YourTest(unittest.TestCase):
    PATH = 'home/luis/test'

    def test_foo(self):
        # do your thing with PATH

    def test_bar(self):
        # do your other thing with PATH

class YourOtherTest(YourTest):
    PATH = 'home/luis/other-directory'
```

The unit test engine will find two classes that are subclasses of `TestCase`, and it will execute every method that starts with `test_` in both of them.  I.e. `test_foo` will be executed with both paths, and so will `test_bar`.

Unit tests are not benchmarks, they check if something is true or false about a unit of code.

You could also just not inherit from TestCase and just have a class with two methods that is instantiated and run explicitly from your main.  Then you wouldn't polute the test cases in your code base with benchmark stuff.

EDIT: there is nothing wrong with testing code that search files against actual files. Its just that you mentioned performance in the question, and that scared me off :)